# Jquery Mobile overlapping listview bug?

Tags: jquery-mobile

How to correctly write tag so that elements after a listview are not overlapping the listview?

Code snippet:

```
<div data-role="content">
    This test is wrongly hidden            
    <div>
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li>
            <li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li>
            <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <button>Why is this button overlapping the listview above?</button>        
</div>
```

[JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arvinboggs/Stdzs/7/)

I hope that this is not a jQuery Mobile bug.

Thanx in advance for you help.

Comment: duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682934/jquery-mobile-listview-and-input-button-overlap . how do i remove my own question? thanx

Comment: i made a fix: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12757598/334045